# How to Stop a .mouseenter() Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a sketchpad of sorts similar to [this](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/donaldali/odin-webdev101/blob/master/project_js_jquery/index.html). I have the following function to define what type of drawing the user will do: black and white, random colors, or shades of gray. The user decides which case to use by clicking on different buttons which each call a separate case:

```
switch (colorMode){
    case 'bw':
        $(".grid").mouseenter(function(){ 
            $(this).css('background-color', "#EEEEEE");
        });
        break;
    case 'randomColor':
        $(".grid").mouseenter(function(){
            var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16); //random number between 0 and 1, nultiplied by largest hexidecimal/color value, and the converted to a string.
            $(this).css('background-color', "#" + randomColor);
        });
        break;
    case 'fading':
        $(".grid").mouseenter(function(){
            var currentColor = $(this).css('background-color').slice(4, -1).split(', ');
            var newColor = [];
            for (i=0; i<currentColor.length; i++){
                newColor[i] = Math.round(parseInt(currentColor[i]) - (parseInt(currentColor[i])*.1));
            }
            var rgbString = "rgb(" + newColor[0] + "," + newColor[1] + "," + newColor[2] + ")"; 
            $(this).css('background-color', rgbString);
        });
        break;
}
```

The unexpected behavior that I'm running into is that instead of replacing the previous mouseenter effect, when the user clicks a button to use a different case, they are ADDING a mouseenter effect. Meaning that if the user does black and white, switches to color, and then back to black and white, each .grid will change to gray, a random color, and then back to gray. This is unseen by the user, but is not ideal. Especially, as it is messing with my fading effect. Is there a way to replace the mouseenter effects? Or kill previous ones? Do I just need to find a new structure for my code?

Comment: Elements can have more than one event listener for the same event. "Killing the previous" would probably be the simplest solution in your case. See https://api.jquery.com/off/ .

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make the `switch` inside the event handler:

```
$(".grid").mouseenter(function(){
    switch(colorMode) {
         //...
    }
});
```

This way, the event handler will be bound only once.